How to efficiently determine if certain azimuth heading is crossed during satellite pass in SkyField
I am trying to determine if an upcoming satellite pass in SkyField will cross a certain azimuth heading, say 0.0 deg north. Right now I iterate in 1 sec steps "manually" over the entire pass from risetime to settime to check if the azimuth heading crosses 0.0 degrees. However this approach is very inefficient and takes too long for satellites in MEO/HEO with long passes.
Does anyone have a better approach how this could be achieved?
(Background story is I have a tracking platform which has limited azimuth range due to cable wrap from 0.0 - 360.0 so I need to know if the satellite pass will cross through north, in which case I flip the pass to not be limited by the azimuth travel limit.)
